# prevent form from submitting to a different page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code:

```
<form method="get" action="" id="search">
<input id="search_box" name="search" type="text" class='search_box'  onkeypress="if(event.keyCode==13) sentAjax('searchdata.php');var filelink='searchdata.php';"  value="" onclick="this.value=''" />
        <input type="hidden" name="course_val" id="course_val" />
</form>
```

I want to block the form from submitting to a different page.Now if you hit enter it submits to a different page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in pure javascript

```
<form method="get" action="" id="search" onsubmit="return false;">
...
</form>
```

Please note that will not let you submit the form so ideally you would invoke your submit handler function in which you would control when you want to submit

```
<form method="get" action="" id="search" onsubmit="return mySubmitHandler()">
...
</form>
```

and in your submit handler

```
        function mySubmitHandler(){
        if (submit_criteria_met) {
        return true;
        } else {
        return false;
        }
return false;

    }
```

Comment: np. just corrected the submit handler pseudo code. the onsubmit should have "return mySubmitHandler()".

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
$('form#search').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

The important part being [`e.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.preventDefault), which prevents the form submitting when it's `submit` event is triggered.

Comment: This won’t prevent the onkeypress handler from executing when pressing enter (keycode 13). See my answer

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `onkeypress` attribute in the input field, it looks like it does some posting behind the curtains when pressing enter (keycode 13).

You might also want to prevent the form from submitting, although it seems to submit to the same page since the action attribute is empty.

If you are unable to edit the HTML, try something like:

```
$('#search').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}).find('input[onkeypress]').removeAttr('onkeypress');
```

Test: http://jsfiddle.net/DAvfm/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#search').bind('submit',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: That will do a whole lot of nothing :)

Comment: Well in your form if you are using get method why don't you get rid of the form and post it as a URL? In any case its not going to benefit in anyways.

Comment: oops! i didn't prevent the typo :)

Comment: yeah didnt work. thanks Abhi, its a complicated ajax/mysql search I figured the best way to achieve the results needed is to prevent from submitting

Answer (score 0):

Prevent the default action of the form.

```
$('#search').submit(function(event) { event.preventDefault(); });
```